# IE Extention/Plugin/Addon javascript injection in iframe and document c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

I am facing issue with BHO in C# ,Javascript not inject in iframe .

[How to get access of <iframe> body using c++/ATL/COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282584/how-to-get-access-of-iframe-body-using-c-atl-com)
 question is similar like but in this above using com. i want to use C#.

Comment: Accessing body (at least some data) in a iframe with IE plugin Browser Helper Object (BHO)  --------   Similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119581/accessing-body-at-least-some-data-in-a-iframe-with-ie-plugin-browser-helper-ob

Comment: Same Question asking in  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965171/access-a-span-inside-iframe-using-mshtml

Answer (score 0):

I have created a IE extension/Plugin/Addon To inject my Custom JavaScript on page as well as on IFrame attache with the document

So I created BHO in c# . in Document complete Event

```
        private void webBrowser_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        // this is main docuemnt
        document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IHTMLElementCollection elcol = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        foreach (IHTMLElement _htmlElement in elcol)
        {
            try
            {
                //This line is for specific iframe on body
                //string fUrl = ((mshtml.HTMLIFrameClass)_htmlElement).IHTMLFrameBase_src;
                //if (fUrl.Contains("/v1/api/login?isIframe=true"))
                //{
                // in this casting HtmlElement HTMLFrameElement
                HTMLFrameElement frmelement = (HTMLFrameElement)_htmlElement;

                //from HTMLFrameElement Casting as a WebBrowser2 because it will give us body of i frame and works a document .
                DispHTMLDocument doc2 = (DispHTMLDocument)((SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)frmelement).Document;

                //no Doc2 is documnt without access denied .. do what ever you want to do

                //Here i am checking wheather document having body or not
                if (doc2.body != null)
                {
                    //Here i am checking Already injected or not if not then inject my javascript here
                    if (doc2.getElementById("UniqueDivVishal") == null)
                    {
                        IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc2.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
                        IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc2.createElement("script");
                        scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
                        scriptObject.text = Properties.Resources.SearchHelper1;
                        ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);

                        string div2 = "<div id=\"UniqueDivVishal\"></div>";
                        doc2.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", div2);
                    }

                    //execute a function from BHO which is in Iframe
                    doc2.parentWindow.execScript("funcation(){ InitFn(); alert('Hello From Frame')}", "javascript");

                }
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //Handle Exception here //                   
            }
        }
    }
```

for further detail you can contact me : vishalroxx7@gmail.com